# Table section heading with newline different on iPad and iPhone

Tags: ios, ios7

I want to put a 2-line section heading in a UITableView.

Edited a bit for clarity and to simplify the code.

It works on the iPhone (iOS 5/6/7) to use a label and simply assign a text value with a newline in it:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UILabel *label = [UILabel new];
    label.numberOfLines = 0;
    heading = @"First Line \nSecond Line";
    label.text = heading;
    [label sizeToFit];
    return label; 
}
```

This code prints 2 line heading on an iPhone and iPad on iOS 5, but on iPad with iOS 6/7 it prints a single line with truncated text.  iOS 7 truncates at the newline and follows with an ellipsis.  Same result for text and attributed text.

The sizeToFit is working correctly, the label bounds.size.height is twice that of a single-line label -- although I don't think that matters since it works on the iPhone before I added any call to sizeToFit -- the UITableView must do that for me.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm using Xcode 5.0.2 on Mountain Lion. iOS 7.0.4 on my iPad.

Comment: Running into similar problem with iOS 7.0.4, did you find your solution?

Comment: I didn't ever find a solution.  Sorry.  I haven't looked at it since 7.0.4.